# What is does monit mean by FIFO?

Tags: monit

I'm just curious what it means in the documentation when it's talking about monitoring a FIFO?

I'd kind of like to be able to monitor a stream of logs for particular recurring errors and take an action on that. This *sounds* like FIFO, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Monit is referring to a "First In, First Out" queue:

> a method for organizing and manipulating a data buffer, where the
>   oldest (first) entry, or 'head' of the queue, is processed first.

See [FIFO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO_(computing_and_electronics)) for more information

Comment: Ah as in a named pipe. Very interesting. Do people use this to monitor logs?

Comment: It is used for monitoring queues more often than logs. For example, a message-sending queue, to make sure that the messages are flowing in a timely manner.